# ParameterNameDiscover Jsr303 method parameter Validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate-validator

I'using Spring 4.1.1 with Hibernate Validator 5.1.3. I'm trying to validate method parameter with the JSR303 validation, and It can't retrieve the parameter's name of the validated method because spring apply validation on the interface, but the parameter's names are in the compiled implementation class.

Interface :
Code:

```
@Validated
public interface NomenclatureVenteRest {

public Response recupererArborescenceNomenclatureVente(
   @FieldValidation(required="dateAppli") StimeDate dateAppli,
   @FieldValidation(check = GENE_M010_PAYS) String codePays,
   @FieldValidation(check = GENE_M010_ENSEIGNE) List<String> listeCodeEns) throws StimeFunctionalException;
}
```

Implementation :
Code:

```
@Path("/")
@Service(value = "nomenclatureVenteRestImpl")
public class NomenclatureVenteRestImpl implements NomenclatureVenteRest {
   
    @GET
    @Path("/")
    @Produces(RestUtils.UTF8_ENCODED_JSON)
    @Override
    public Response recupererArborescenceNomenclatureVente(
      @QueryParam("dateAppli") StimeDate dateAppli,
      @QueryParam("codePays")String codePays,
      @QueryParam("listeCodeEns")List<String> listeCodeEns) throws StimeFunctionalException{
   
      ...Business logic...
    }
}
```

@FieldValidation is my custom constraint validation

```
@Target({ PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE ,FIELD})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = FieldValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface FieldValidation {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    boolean required() default false;

    FieldTypeValidator[] check() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I want tu use the parameter name in my validator :

```
public class FieldValidator implements ConstraintValidator<FieldValidation, Object>, ApplicationContextAware {

    ApplicationContext context;

    private boolean fieldRequired;
    private FieldTypeValidator[] fieldCheck;

    @Override
    public final void initialize(final FieldValidation annotation) {
    fieldCheck = annotation.check();
    fieldRequired = annotation.required();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean isValid(final Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {

    //If I take look a the constraintValidatorContext.methodParameterNames contains ["arg0", "arg1", "arg2"] , but I need the real parameter names ["dateAppli","codePays","listeCodeEns"]


    return true;
    }
```

Jsr303 configuration :

```
<!-- JSR 303 validation -->
<bean id="validator"
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" />
<bean
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.MethodValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
</bean>

<bean
class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.BeanValidationPostProcessor">
    <property name="validator" ref="validator" />
</bean>
```

Comment: How do you retrieve the parameter name? Which ParameterNameProvider are you using? Or are you talking about @QueryParam? Hibernate Validator has indeed no knowledge about it. Where do you need the parameter name and how do you want to use it?

Comment: the parameter name is retrieved with the spring LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer (I did not configure a specific provider , it uses the default one). I need the parameter name in my validator to generate generic validation message .I ve just added my custom constraint annotation